# Error's with jQuery JSON

Tags: jquery, json

Trying to make a login function, it will say Logging in Please wait and when it does the PHP crap at the back, it will say all of the errors that it gives when you have done something wrong. Except, it redirects to the backend page. and just shows plain text.

```
    function login(){
    $('#infobox').fadeIn();
    $('#infobox').html("Logging in, please wait ...");
    dataString = $('#login').serialize();
    var postURL = $('#login').attr("action");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: postURL,
        data:dataString,
        dataType:"json",
        cache:false,
        success:function(data){
            if(data.err){
                $('#errbox').fadeIn();
                $('#errbox').html(data.err);
            }else if(data.msg){
                $('#infobox').fadeIn();
                $('#infobox').html(data.msg);

                var delay = 2000;
                window.setTimeout(function(){          
                    location.reload(true);
                }, delay);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

And right here is PHP

```
//retun errors and msg's
$return_json = array();

if($err==""){ $return_json['msg'] = $msg; }
else{ $return_json['err'] = $err; }
echo json_encode($return_json); 
exit;
```

This is the "JSON" part of the PHP, but let's say it logs you in and says welcome to the site which I have here.

```
$msg = 'You have successfully logged in, welcome '.$userInput.'';
```

It will instead show this result.

```
{"msg":"You have successfully logged in, welcome Cameron"}
```

Just keep in mind, that's all it will show, just plain text like this. I've done the Header javascript code that a few people suggested and nothing helped.

Comment: Maybe u will give link to Your website?

Comment: It's on localhost, sorry.

Comment: What returns php in Your browser console? What is data type of returned content?

Comment: http://i.gyazo.com/e36f6a1a9610f06eddc060b7aed8f13e.png

The first 3 lines are the variables that I echo'd manually for testing purposes and the last line is what the return_json is suppose to send to the login modal on the site.

Comment: What is datatype in Your console? (network tab)

Comment: http://i.gyazo.com/21a07ac736062e23eaa264339cfa4024.png

Comment: What about the JS code that calls your `login()` function? Can we see that? Also, when you say `it redirects to the backend page`, do you mean that the browser is taken to the login script rather than an AJAX call being made? It kind of sounds like the default action, a click event or a submit event most likely, is not being stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `application/json` as `Content-type` in Your PHP file.

Best idea is setting it before any code which can display any error or other content.

So just add this to begin of Your `login.php` file.

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
```

Comment: And working good? If no, please give me what returns `login.php` in Your console.